# I am seeing this error in terminal "You cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path" and also localhost:3000 is refusing to connect

Tags: localhost, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I only have one dynamic path in my whole Next.js project, that is, `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js`

But for some reason I'm seeing the mentioned error with a elaborated line, that is, `You cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path ('nextAuth' !== 'nextauth')`

I can't also see the `localhost:3000` and I don't know if those are two different errors or the dynamic path error is causing the latter.

I admit that I'm new to Next.js and I'll be very thankful if anyone can help me out.

[image]

[image]